# Angular 8 UI model binding with a view model prefix (vm)

Tags: angular

Our team is currently re-writing an AngularJS application to Angular 8+. Our existing structure uses `vm.model` as our view model in AngularJS. The following reference article (and other sources) seem to move away from using a `vm.*` prefix.
https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference

We're early in development; and have starting using a centralized model `vm.*` prefix for UI model binding. The prefix is familiar and helps with centralizing model sharing to the UI. (example below).

```
vm: any;

let model = new CartItem();
let product = initData['product'] as Product;

this.vm = {
  model: model,
  selectedProduct: product
};
```

We do not have a registered Angular 8 expert on our team, but we're all Angular 1.x-perts. Therefore we are without guidance on this approach.

Is there a long term negative impact to using a `vm.*` prefix for our object binding? Is there any reason you can point to why this approach is a bad idea?

Comment: It's unnecessary since controllers have been replaced by components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have seen it, components have 3 files:

- html
- css/sass/scss
- ts

So, for example in `foo.component.ts` (I use .sass)

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-foo',
    templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./foo.component.sass']
})
export class FooComponent {
    itIsAAttirbute: number = 0; // html only read
    inputAttr: string = ''; // read-write
    anotherText: string = 'string'; // pass into "another-componenet"

    construct() {
        setInterval(() => { this.itIsAAttirbute++; }, 1000);
    }

    clickEventMethod() {
        // code
    }
}
```

`foo.component.html`

```html
<p>{{ itIsAAttirbute }}</p>

<input [(ngModel)]="inputAttr"/>

<another-component [componentInputProperty]="anotherText" (click)="clickEventMethod()">
<another-component>
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview

So, you can see it and all attributes. Not need model. Ofc, if you would like to use `<form>` I don't recommand `[(ngModel)]`. Use them:

- https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
- or
- https://angular.io/guide/forms

Or you define a class what description a model with "interface" and "class".

I recommend: https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/

---

**Update: I wrote it after #1 comment of nesterenes.**

Your idea just depend on implementation. Possible. `vm` just a object.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-foo',
    templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./foo.component.sass']
})
export class FooComponent {
    vm = {
        itIsAAttirbute: number = 0; // html only read
        inputAttr: string = ''; // read-write
        anotherText: string = 'string'; // pass into "another-componenet"
    };

    construct() {
        setInterval(() => { this.vm.itIsAAttirbute++; }, 1000);
    }

    clickEventMethod() {
        // code
    }
}
```

```html
<p>{{ vm.itIsAAttirbute }}</p>

<input [(ngModel)]="vm.inputAttr"/>

<another-component [componentInputProperty]="vm.anotherText" (click)="clickEventMethod()">
<another-component>
```

Comment: Based on your example I would simply re-write it this. My question is - why would this be a bad idea to bucket everything under a single `vm.*` object prefix? I assume 1-way and 2-way data binding can still happen on the nested objects? Is there a performance impact?

    `<p>{{ vm.itIsAAttirbute }}</p>`

   ` <input [(ngModel)]="vm.inputAttr"/>`

   ` <another-component [componentInputProperty]="vm.anotherText" (click)="clickEventMethod()">`
    `<another-component>`

Comment: Ofc, You can't use this methodology directly with decorations like `@Output`, `@Input`, `@View...`, `@Content...` because decorations bind to attributes or methods of class.